# c# errorprovider de text box dentro de un groupbox

Tags: c#

Dejo mi codigo:

```
public static Boolean ValidadFormulario(Control Objeto, ErrorProvider error)
        {
            Boolean HayErrores = false;

            foreach (Control Item in Objeto.Controls)
            {
                if (Item is ErrorTextBox)
                {
                    ErrorTextBox obj = (ErrorTextBox)Item;

                    if (obj.Validar == true)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            error.SetError(obj, "No puede estar vacio");
                            HayErrores = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        error.SetError(obj, "");

                    }
                }
            }
            return HayErrores;
        }
```

Este es el método que ejecuto en el evento del botón al ser presionado. Cuando el ErrorTextBox esta fuera del groupBox, funciona perfecto, pero ahora, cuando esta dentro del groupBox, no funciona.

Como se puede solucionar para que quede el ErrorTextBox dentro del groupBox y funcione este metodo?

```
 if (ValidadFormulario(this, errorProvider1) == false){}
```

adjunto captura, de como los ErrorTextBox dentro del groupBox no funcionan correctamente y el que esta fuera del groupBox Sí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este caso requiere un llamado recursivo al método `ValidadFormulario` porque el `GroupBox` es un contenedor que también debe ser recorrido para validar los controles que agrupa.

```
public static Boolean ValidadFormulario(Control Objeto, ErrorProvider error)
{
    Boolean HayErrores = false;

    foreach (Control Item in Objeto.Controls)
    {
        if (Item is ErrorTextBox)
        {
            // ...
            // Código omitido para mantener el foco en el área de interés
            // ...
        }

        // |   Agrega este bloque else if...
        // V
        else if (Item is GroupBox)
        {
            ValidadFormulario(Item, error);
        }
    }
    return HayErrores;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que puedes hacerlo más genérico utilizando `(Item.HasChildren)` en lugar de `(Item is GroupBox)` pero recomiendo cautela con este enfoque porque puede ser innecesario ya que en controles como PictureBox o DataGridView la propiedad `HasChildren` es `true`

```
        else if (Item.HasChildren)
        {
            ValidadFormulario(Item, error);
        }
```